# Create customized auto increment ID in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, auto-increment

I have a list in SharePoint where I need to have a auto incremented customized ID when an item is created. I know SharePoint list already has a default ID but I need my ID to be customized with a code.
Example: my ID should display as AMS-0001

I have a solution but it gives the same ID every time a new item is created.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What is your solution? Did you try calculated field?

Comment: Yes I created a calculated column and used a formula to derive the ID which is ="USL-"&REPT(0,4-LEN(ID))&ID. But still the same ID recurs and couldnt get the output as expected

Comment: This may also help the newcomers **[Use SharePoint ID Field in Calculated Column](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/id-field-in-calaulated-column-sharepoint/)**  and **[Auto Serial Number in SharePoint New Form using JSOM](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/auto-serial-number-new-form-sharepoint/)**

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new column, such as : Increment Number in issue list with Number type. Make this column hidden in a view.
2. Create another column, such as : Issue No. in issue list with Formula type and add the following formula = "AMS-00" & [Increment Number]. This Column will show the increment items’ numbers in the list.
3. Open SharePoint designer, create new list workflow (for issues list).
4. Add a workflow action: “Update list Item” >> Current Item >> Add >> Set this field to your Target field (Increment Number), set value from Current Item:ID field (as below):

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[How to Create an Auto-Incrementing Number Field in a SharePoint List](https://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/how-to-create-an-auto-incrementing-number-field-in-a-sharepoint-list/)

Comment: Hi, this solution is awesome but unfortunately I don't use SharePoint designer and I have created this list using SharePoint online. Any other possible method? Anyways thank you for sharing this awesome solution.

Comment: Calculated column won't work for new created items, for this case, the solution above is the best option. You could download SharePoint Designer, this is for free to use and could download here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/details.aspx?id=35491