# (SharePoint) Generating unique numerical ID number using info from other columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I'm fairly new to building SharePoint sites so bear with me. I am trying to use a calculated value in the default SharePoint ID column and was wondering if it would be possible to generate a unique ID number that tells more information.

The ID format I'm thinking of would look something like this:

2021-123-001

Here's what the digits mean:
[Year]-[Item number]-[Type of request]

The year is pretty straightforward and I do have the formula up to that part. The item number could just be a regular count but I haven't figured out how to do that. And the type of request would be determined from the type of request that is submitted which is info from a different column:

Print Advertisement = 001
Social Media = 002
Client Communication = 003

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please following steps:**

1.Enable "**Require that this column contains information**" and "**Enforce unique values**" option for the following columns

- ItemNumber --- Single line of text
- Type of Request --- Choice

[image]

2.Create the first Calculated column named "**Year**"

**Formula:**

```
=TEXT(Created,"yyyy")
```

[image]

3.Create the second Calculated column named "**TypesID**"

**Formula:**

```
=IF([Type of Request]="Print Advertisement","001",IF([Type of Request]="Social Media","002","003"))
```

[image]

4.Create the third Calculated column named "**UniqueID**"

**Formula:**

```
=CONCATENATE([Year],"-",[ItemNumber],"-",[TypesID])
```

[image]

[image]

5.You can hide the "Year" and "TypesID" column in the list view

[image]

[image]

Comment: bro, ur a god.....thank u

Answer (score 0):

First please refer to this old thread about how to create increment ID in SP online:
[Create customized auto increment ID in SharePoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/262586/create-customized-auto-increment-id-in-sharepoint-online)

After you created the column [IncrementID]. Then your need calculated column will be:

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(Created),"-",[IncrementID],"-",IF(Title="Print Advertisement","001",IF(Title="Social Media","002","003")))
```